# Sum up values in data table for two specific column entries

Tags: r

I have the following data table:

```
dt.data <- structure(list(delivMonth = c("2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", 
"2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", 
"2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", 
"2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12"), quantity = c(-3600, 1440, 0, 
-34560, 5760, 0, 7200, 3600, 720, 993.6, 1800, 734.4, 720, -13680, 
18252, -842.4, 2880, -3600, -2160, 3600, -3600, 43272, 0, 3600, 
-1420.56, 20534.4, 835.2, 345.6, 2160, -7200, -14400, 5040, 720, 
-10800, 360, 3600, 1980, 720, -3720, 1488, 0, -35712, 5952, 0, 
-7440, 744, 1026.72, 1860, 758.88, 744, -4464, 18860.4, -870.48, 
2976, -2232, 3720, -3720, 33554.4, 0, -1467.91, 15266.88, 863.04, 
357.12, 2232, -7440, -3720, 5208, 744, 372, 3720, 2046, 744, 
-3600, 1440, 0, -34560, 5760, 0, -7200, 720, 993.6, 1800, 734.4, 
720, -720, 18252, -842.4, 2880, -2160, 3600, -3600, 32472, 0, 
-1420.56, 11174.4, 835.2, 345.6, 2160, -7200, -3600, 5040, 720, 
360, 3600, 1980, 720, -3720, 1488, -3720, -35712, 5952, 0, -3720, 
3720, 744, 1026.72, 1860, 758.88, 744, -744, 18860.4, -870.48, 
2976, 0, -2232, 3720, -3720, 32810.4, 0, -1467.91, 11546.88, 
863.04, 357.12, -1488, -7440, -7440, 5208, 744, 372, 3720, 3720, 
2046, 744, -3720, 1488, -3720, -35712, 5952, 0, -3720, 3720, 
744, 1026.72, 1860, 758.88, 744, -744, 18860.4, -870.48, 2976, 
0, -2232, 3720, -3720, 32810.4, 0, -1467.91, 11546.88, 863.04, 
357.12, -1488, -7440, -7440, 5208, 744, 372, 3720, 3720, 2046, 
744, -3600, 1440, -3600, -34560, 5760, 0, -3600, 3600, 720, 993.6, 
1800, 734.4, 720, -4320, 18252, -842.4, 2880, 0, -2160, 3600, 
-3600, 31752, 0, -1420.56, 14774.4, 835.2, 345.6, -1440, -7200, 
-7200, 5040, 720, 360, 3600, 3600, 1980, 720, 35015, 1490, 0, 
21605, 5960, 0, 4470, 1028.1, 1862.5, 759.9, 745, -2980, 18885.75, 
-871.65, 2980, 3725, -3725, 32854.5, 0, -1469.89, 12307.4, 864.2, 
357.6, 12665, -7450, -3725, 5215, 745, 372.5, 3725, 2048.75, 
745, 33840, 1440, 0, 20880, 5760, 0, 4320, 993.6, 1800, 734.4, 
720, -7200, 18252, -842.4, 2880, 3600, -3600, 31752, 0, -1420.56, 
11894.4, 835.2, 345.6, 12240, -7200, -3600, 5040, 720, 360, 3600, 
1980, 720, 34968, 1488, 0, 21576, 5952, 0, 4464, 1026.72, 1860, 
758.88, 744, -22320, 18860.4, -870.48, 2976, 3720, -3720, 32810.4, 
0), counterparty = c("Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "Shell (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", 
"Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", 
"HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", 
"Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"DXT Commodities (CH)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"Mercuria (CH)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "Vitol (CH)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "Vitol (CH)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "Vitol (CH)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)"), marketArea = c("CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE")), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Now I want to sum up the `quantity` for only two specific `counterparty` per `marketArea` and `delivDate`. I want to sum up the `quantity` for `counterparty` = **RWE (DE)** and `counterparty` = **RWE (GB)**. All other data table entries should stay the same.

I have already tried many versions with summarize(), group_by() and so on, but I don't get it.

How can I handle this?

Comment: What do you mean by "*should stay the same*"?

Comment: I want to have the same data table. The only difference should be that two of the counterparties should be summed up to one RWE entry.

Comment: Well, I do not understand. Do you want to aggreagte those or should each row remain?

Comment: I want to sum up the quantities of two specific counterparties, namely RWE (GB) & RWE (DE). All other counterparties should be summed up. Instead of two row-entries for RWE per delivDate and marketArea, I want one summed up.

Comment: *"I want to sum up the quantities of two specific counterparties, namely RWE (GB) & RWE (DE). All other counterparties should be summed up."* That does not make sense.

Comment: Sorry here the edit: "I want to sum up the quantities of two specific counterparties, namely RWE (GB) & RWE (DE). All other counterparties should not be summed up. Instead of two row-entries for RWE per delivDate and marketArea, I want one summed up."

Comment: You do not show what have you tried. Take this just as an educational intro to develope something more concise: `X = split(dt.data,  dt.data$counterparty %in% c("RWE (GB)", "RWE (DE)")); X[[2]]$counterparty = "RWE (DE/GB)"
; X[[2]] = aggregate(quantity ~ ., X[[2]], sum); dt.data = rbind(X[[1]], X[[2]])`.

Comment: Thank you! This works for me now. I wouldn't have thought of that, since I'm not familiar with the 'stats' package and thus the aggregate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a `data.table` not a `tibble` so you should look at the `data.table` package for data wrangling not `tidyverse` functions. A good introduction is here:  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

If I understand correctly, you want to combine the entries for `RWE (DE)` and `RWE (GB)` by summing.

One approach would be to rename this counterparty to (eg) `RWE (DE/GB)` and then to sum the data table over the new counterparty variable.

So:

```
# First assign RWE (DE) and RWE (GB) to a new counterparty called RWE (DE/GB)
dt.data[ counterparty %in% c("RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)"), counterparty := "RWE (DE/GB)"]

# Now sum quantity over counterparty, date and market area:
dt.data2 = dt.data[ ,.(quantity=sum(quantity)), by=.(counterparty,delivMonth, marketArea)]
```

which gives you 276 rows instead of the 300 you had initially, with the quantities summed as you expect:

```
> dt.data2
         counterparty delivMonth marketArea quantity
               <char>     <char>     <char>    <num>
  1:        Axpo (CH)    2024-04       CEGH  -3600.0
  2:        Axpo (CH)    2024-04        THE   1440.0
  3:        Axpo (CH)    2024-04        TTF      0.0
  4:         CEZ (CZ)    2024-04       CEGH -34560.0
  5:         CEZ (CZ)    2024-04        THE   5760.0
 ---                                                
272:      Gunvor (CH)    2024-12        THE   2976.0
273:    Mercuria (CH)    2024-12       CEGH   3720.0
274:    Mercuria (CH)    2024-12        TTF  -3720.0
275: OMV Gas M&T (AT)    2024-12       CEGH  32810.4
276: OMV Gas M&T (AT)    2024-12        THE      0.0
```

---

You can check that the 48 rows with `counterparty %in% c("RWE (DE)","RWE (GB)")` have been reduced to 24 rows in the new dataset:

```
> dt.data2[ counterparty == "RWE (DE/GB)"]
    counterparty delivMonth marketArea  quantity
          <char>     <char>     <char>     <num>
 1:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-04       CEGH  22694.40
 2:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-04        THE  -6364.80
 3:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-04        TTF -14054.40
 4:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-05       CEGH  17498.88
 5:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-05        THE  -6576.96
 6:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-05        TTF  -3362.88
 7:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-06       CEGH  13334.40
 8:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-06        THE  -6364.80
 9:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-06        TTF  -3254.40
10:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-07       CEGH  10058.88
11:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-07        THE  -6576.96
12:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-07        TTF  -7082.88
13:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-08       CEGH  10058.88
14:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-08        THE  -6576.96
15:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-08        TTF  -7082.88
16:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-09       CEGH  13334.40
17:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-09        THE  -6364.80
18:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-09        TTF  -6854.40
19:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-10       CEGH  24972.40
20:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-10        THE  -6585.80
21:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-10        TTF  -3367.40
22:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-11       CEGH  24134.40
23:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-11        THE  -6364.80
24:  RWE (DE/GB)    2024-11        TTF  -3254.40
    counterparty delivMonth marketArea  quantity
```

in the data before summing:

```
> dt.data[ counterparty == "RWE (DE)" | counterparty == "RWE (GB)"]
    delivMonth  quantity counterparty marketArea
        <char>     <num>       <char>     <char>
 1:    2024-04  20534.40     RWE (DE)       CEGH
 2:    2024-04    835.20     RWE (DE)        THE
 3:    2024-04    345.60     RWE (DE)        TTF
 4:    2024-04   2160.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
 5:    2024-04  -7200.00     RWE (GB)        THE
 6:    2024-04 -14400.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
 7:    2024-05  15266.88     RWE (DE)       CEGH
 8:    2024-05    863.04     RWE (DE)        THE
 9:    2024-05    357.12     RWE (DE)        TTF
10:    2024-05   2232.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
11:    2024-05  -7440.00     RWE (GB)        THE
12:    2024-05  -3720.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
13:    2024-06  11174.40     RWE (DE)       CEGH
14:    2024-06    835.20     RWE (DE)        THE
15:    2024-06    345.60     RWE (DE)        TTF
16:    2024-06   2160.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
17:    2024-06  -7200.00     RWE (GB)        THE
18:    2024-06  -3600.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
19:    2024-07  11546.88     RWE (DE)       CEGH
20:    2024-07    863.04     RWE (DE)        THE
21:    2024-07    357.12     RWE (DE)        TTF
22:    2024-07  -1488.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
23:    2024-07  -7440.00     RWE (GB)        THE
24:    2024-07  -7440.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
25:    2024-08  11546.88     RWE (DE)       CEGH
26:    2024-08    863.04     RWE (DE)        THE
27:    2024-08    357.12     RWE (DE)        TTF
28:    2024-08  -1488.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
29:    2024-08  -7440.00     RWE (GB)        THE
30:    2024-08  -7440.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
31:    2024-09  14774.40     RWE (DE)       CEGH
32:    2024-09    835.20     RWE (DE)        THE
33:    2024-09    345.60     RWE (DE)        TTF
34:    2024-09  -1440.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
35:    2024-09  -7200.00     RWE (GB)        THE
36:    2024-09  -7200.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
37:    2024-10  12307.40     RWE (DE)       CEGH
38:    2024-10    864.20     RWE (DE)        THE
39:    2024-10    357.60     RWE (DE)        TTF
40:    2024-10  12665.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
41:    2024-10  -7450.00     RWE (GB)        THE
42:    2024-10  -3725.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
43:    2024-11  11894.40     RWE (DE)       CEGH
44:    2024-11    835.20     RWE (DE)        THE
45:    2024-11    345.60     RWE (DE)        TTF
46:    2024-11  12240.00     RWE (GB)       CEGH
47:    2024-11  -7200.00     RWE (GB)        THE
48:    2024-11  -3600.00     RWE (GB)        TTF
    delivMonth  quantity counterparty marketArea
```